# Force a user to enter a variable in the UI before running a pipeline in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an existing YAML Azure Dev Ops Pipeline.

In order to build/ deploy a new release, users have to press the `Run Pipeline` button in Azure Dev Ops.

[image]

Which brings up the following menu:

[image]

I would, at this point, like to ask the user to set the value of a variable.
[image]

Something to prompt them & prevent them from proceeding.
Is that possible to do via a YAML pipeline?
If so, how can I achieve this?

The idea is for me to ask the user for an input before allowing them to proceed & create a new build etc. as there is a build step which relies on said variable to be set prior to build.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can make a variable as mandatory, but as you said, you can add a simple step to check if the user is put some value:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      if($env:testVariable -eq "")
      {
          Write-Error "testVariable variable is empty!"
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following YAML code, yu can achieve something like below.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: Mode
    displayName: Specify the mode
    default: DEV
    type: string
```

[image]

The parameter must be referenced in the template using **${{ parameters.Mode}}** , the other variable syntaxes don't work.